# Cast char* to double - as bytes

Tags: c++, casting, double, c-strings

I have a byte array that represents double:

```
char number[8];
```

I need to cast this to actual double (which has 8 bytes as well). Based on advice I tried this, but it failed:

```
std::cout<<(*((*double)number))<<" is my number.\n";
```

Why did it fail and what should I do? I can, of course, extract the data using some `<<` magic, but I don't want to do this - it would consume memory and make code too robust.

Comment: Type-punning like this is rather dangerous (though valid in the specific case of `char` IIRC, at least for now and as long as you only use one type). In general, a `union` is safer, and more convenient too. With pointers, strict aliasing is always out to get you.

Comment: @delnan, But reading from a member of a union that wasn't set last is UB, where as this is implementation-defined (at least the casting is IIRC).

Comment: @chris You won't get anything better than implementation-defined, the standard doesn't even specify how many bits there are in a `char`. However, implementation-defined is much better than undefined behavior (which is what you get with stuff like `*(int*)&a_double` IIRC). More importantly, even if both are equally broken by the standard, many compilers perform type-based alias analysis which can break code doing type punning with pointers, but doesn't break type punning via unions IIUC.

Comment: I hate it when my code is too robust. Use `memcpy` to copy the bytes into a double, the compiler will make it just as fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why did it fail?

You have a typo here.

```
std::cout<<(*((*double)number))<<" is my number.\n";
```

It should be:

```
std::cout<<(*((double*)number))<<" is my number.\n";
```

> and what should I do?

You *could* reduce the number of parenthesis used.

```
std::cout<< *(double*)number <<" is my number.\n";
```

You *should* use C++ casts instead of C casts, so it's clear what you're doing.

```
std::cout<< *reinterpret_cast<double*>(number) <<" is my number.\n";
```

Comment: My typos will kill me one day. Thank you :)

Comment: +1 I would recommend to use `reinterpret_cast<double*>(number)` instead of `(double*) number` though.

Comment: @poitroae: This was the first answer, that actually explained why the original code didn't work.

Comment: Don't cry @poitroae. Do not forget it took you 5 edits to make it correct :P.
Rather, I'm wondering why hint about parenthesizes reduction dissapeared.

Comment: @TomášZato Restored.  I worried that I was going on a tangent.  :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use c++, then use **reinterpret_cast**. C++ have much more expressive, as you see.

```
// cool c++
double value = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(number);

// c style
double value = (*((double*)number));
```

Comment: Can I change type of the original variable?

Comment: @OmriBarel: Will it work as `double value = reinterpret_cast<double>(*number);` ?

Comment: @TomášZato No, it should be `*reinterpret_cast<double*>(a)`

Comment: @poitroae Your answer works now. I've tried with `{ 0xF3, 0x8E, 0x53, 0x74, 0x24, 0x97, 0xBF, 0x3F }` which is another way of saying 0.1234 on a little-endian machine.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not *cool c++*, it's just expressing the intent of the cast explicitly.

Comment: @LihO I think they're cool. *This is c++*. The old-style casts are there only for compat.

Comment: @OmriBarel Okay, great! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
char number[8];
double d;
// number is assumed to be filled with a buffer representing a double.
memcpy(&d, &number, sizeof(double));
std::cout << d;
```

Not sure if the sizeof is needed. The damage was already dealt when the assumption that a double is 8 bytes was made. I don't know what it says in the standard about doubles.

Comment: The standard says that a double most be large enough to hold any `float` value, although I'm not sure what the exact wording used is.